# The same style rules applied to div and li tags gives different results

Tags: html, css

*test.html*:

```css
div, li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>тест1</div>

<ul>
  <li>тест</li>
</ul>
```

Opening test.html gives such a result that although div and li tags share the same style rules, div tag content is nevertheless closer to the left screen border than li tag's (at least at Google Chrome 44, desktop). Why is it so and how is it "healed"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<ul>` have some margin from left in default css. You can [reset](http://cssreset.com) your css, or just put to your `<ul>` `margin: 0;` and `padding: 0;`.

Answer (score 1):

HTML elements have styling rules beyond simple left margin & display type (such as padding for example). Also elements are positioned relative to other elements (unless explicitly set otherwise).

There's no reason for your `<div>` & `<li>` to look identical.

Answer (score 1):

Now you get same effect on both:

```
div, li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nphzbfwd/1/

Answer (score 1):

Posting the full code in accordance with @Alesha Oleg's answer-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>
div, li
{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
}  
ul
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
</style>

<div>ABCD</div>

<ul>
  <li>ABCD</li>
</ul>
```